# Django Djoser - переопределение пути для регистрации

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

никак не могу понять как можно переопределить стандартный url для пути регистрации в Djoser.
Вот стандартный путь к регистрации в Djoser.
Я хотел бы иметь такой путь api/new_user/ - для регистрации..

````
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Самой простое - импортировать из *Djoser* необходимые наборы представлений и поставить их на нужные пути. Так же, как это и сделано в самом Djoser.